# How to feature detect Input Events Level 1 or 2 support?

Tags: javascript, input, dom-events, feature-detection

Browser `input` events have been around long enough to be categorised into at least three different levels of support beside "no support", by now (recent history about the W3C specs [on github](https://github.com/w3c/input-events/)):

- InputEvents Level 0? (no `inputType`, nor `beforeinput`, support)
- https://www.w3.org/TR/input-events-1/ (introduces a `beforeinput` event, and the `inputType` property, among other things)
- https://www.w3.org/TR/input-events-2/ (introduces a few new composition related `inputType`s - `deleteByComposition`, `insertCompositionText`, `insertFromComposition`)

How do you detect support for `beforeinput` events? At present time of writing (April 2018), Firefox is at 0, Chrome and Safari further along.

Comment: If you have any feedback on the Input Events specifications, you might wish to [post a new Input Events GitHub issue](https://github.com/w3c/input-events/issues/new). I posted [issue #78](https://github.com/w3c/input-events/issues/78) with a similar question to this one, asking for more developer guidance for choosing between Levels 1 and 2. Hopefully there will be closer consensus between the browser vendors in the future; it seems to still be blocked by lower-level work, e.g., on `Range`s.

Answer (score 3):

My best hack, for the time being, is to construct a synthetic `InputEvent` and test if it has the `inputType` property, and use that as a proxy for "probably supports at least Level 1 of the W3C spec, and, by inference, the `beforeinput` event too":

`const input_events_level_1_or_better = 'inputType' in (new InputEvent('input'));`

Comment: What about Input Level 2 though?